# Help required on UNIX lsof command

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I found some ghost files on RHEL 8 (deleted files from OS but not deleted from MongoDB). I want to check when Ghost files are created. Please help how to check Ghost file creation date time using below command.

```
lsof | grep deleted | grep mongod | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, here's another a better way to run your command:

```
lsof +L 1 -a -c mongod
```

`+L 1` will show all file with a link count smaller than 1 (a deleted file has a link count of zero), `-c mongod` will show processes whose names start with "mongod", and `-a` shows a union of both, ie: All deleted files that are open by processes **and** whose names start with "mongod".

Regarding "Creation time" (called in Linux "Birth time"), it is only supported on a handful of filesystems on Linux. Most filesystems don't support it at all. You can check if your filesystem support Birth time by running `stat <some file>` and checking the "Birth" field.

For instance:

```
$ stat /etc/motd |grep Birth
 Birth: -
```

You can see that in my case, the Birth time is not supported.

However, even if your file system doesn't support the Bith time, you can get some other timestamps of the file that might be useful for you.

First, you should take from the output of `lsof` command the pid of the process, and the file descriptor of the deleted file.

```
$ lsof +L 1 -a -c tail
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NLINK NODE NAME
tail    44305 root    3r   REG   8,10        6     0 4193 /tmp/testfile (deleted)
```

In this case, the pid is **44305**, and the file descriptor (under the `FD`) field is **3**. Than you can run `stat` the deleted file by running: `stat -L /proc/<pid>/fd/<fd number>`

The `-L` flag is to dereference the link of the file descriptor, ie running stat on the file the file descriptor (which is merely a symbolic link) links to rather than the link itself. In my case:

```
$ stat -L /proc/44305/fd/3
  File: '/proc/44305/fd/3'
  Size: 6               Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 80ah/2058d      Inode: 4193        Links: 0
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2022-10-27 16:14:24.519483990 +0300
Modify: 2022-10-27 16:12:06.676463711 +0300
Change: 2022-10-27 16:15:55.425475599 +0300
 Birth: -
```

- `Access` shows the last time the file was accessed, in this case 16:14:24.
- `Modify` shows the last time the content of the file was changed. In this case 16:12:06.
- `Change` usually shows the last time the **metadata* of the file was changed (for instance: owner, user, permissions), but in case of a deleted file, it shows the time the file was deleted. So in my case, the file was deleted at 16:15:55.

Comment: Also note, that some implementations of stat and/or filesystems without Birth-support may set the birth time to the modification-time.

Comment: @stoney do you have any reference for that? Which filesystems/distros show this behavior? A link to an article that corroborates your statement?

Comment: I fcked sth up there. At least when editing (vi would do) it seems to recreate the file. Was a bit of a misthinking on my side.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh` on Linux, you can do:

```
ls -lrtL /proc/*/fd/*(-l0)
```

To check the mtime of the files that are opened on any process fd but are deleted (have a `l`ink cound of `0`).

For those whose path contains `mongo`:

```
ls -lrtL /proc/*/fd/*(-l0e['[[ $REPLY:P = *mongo* ]]'])
```

With relatively recent versions of GNU `ls`, you can add the `--time=birth` to report (and sort by) the birth time instead of last modification time. See also `--full-time` for a more precise time.